# Using Slide In & Slide Out Animations for Subview

Tags: ipad, animation, uiview, subview, uiviewanimation

I will start off by explaining that I have seen many questions and answers regarding this type of feature, but I am still having problems implementing it myself. I am using ARC, and am not using auto-layout or storyboard. I define my layouts with constraints in code, so the way I have been trying to implement my animation is a little different. Lastly, this is an iPad application.

To the specific problem at hand, I have a subview that starts off hidden but appears when an action takes place.  I would like this subview to use the hidden feature, but slide in and out after it appears and before it is hidden.  So far, I have gotten halfway there and am able to get the view to slide in without issue. Below is the code that accomplishes this.

```
    detailView.hidden = NO;

// Perform Animation - Slide In
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    animation.duration = kAnimationTimeout;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(800.0, 0.0, 1.0)];
    [detailView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

However, I have been unsuccessful with trying getting the view to slide out before it is hidden. Below is the code that I added to attempt at completing this feature.

```
// Perform Animation - Slide Out
    CABasicAnimation *animation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
    animation.duration = kAnimationTimeout;
    animation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    animation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(-800.0, 0.0, 1.0)];
    [detailView.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];

    detailView.hidden = YES;
```

The result I get is that the view simply disappears like it was hidden, which it always did. Do I need to remove one animation that is added to a view before I add a different animation? Or is my CATransform3DMakeTranslation incorrectly defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out detailView.hidden was being called before the animation started.  I resolved this by   adding a selector with a delay that contained a method to hide my view.

```
[self performSelector:@selector(hideDetailView) withObject:nil afterDelay:.40];
```